# Fetch API response with react and Express.js won't show any result with console.log

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a login form that sends data to an Express.js backend using `fetch`. On the client side, when I want to display the results of the fetch call when it completes nothing is displayed (and it never reaches the data callback). I don't seem to be getting any errors, but I know that the data is successfully being sent to the backend.

Here's the Express.js server code:

```
const express = require('express');

const User = express.Router();

const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const user = require('../Models/user');
```

> this is edited

```
 function loginRouteHandler(req, res) {
  user.findOne(
    {
      where: {
        userName: req.body.userName,
      },
    },
  )
    .then((data) => {
      if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, data.password)) {
        req.session.userName = req.body.userName;
        req.session.password = req.body.password;
        console.log(req.session);
        res.status(200).send('Success!');
      } else {
        res.status(400).send('some text');
      }
    });
}

    User.route('/').get(getRouteHandler);

    User.route('/register').post(postRouteHandler);

    User.route('/login').post(loginRouteHandler);

    module.exports = User;
```

And here's the fetch call:

```
fetch('http://localhost:4000/login',{
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json,text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    userName: this.state.userName,
    password: this.state.password,

  }),

}).then((response)=>{
if(response.ok){
  console.log(response)
}
else {
  console.log("a problem")
}
}).then((data)=>{
console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: Please don't just say "it failed," could we have the exact error message or what the expected/actual result is? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing is returned in first  `then()` of `fetch` to be passed to `data` argument in second `then()`

Comment: Makes sense, I'll suggest an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `loginRouteHandler`, if the bcrypt compare succeeds nothing is returned in the response. So in the first branch of the if statement, put `res.send('Success!')` or something similar.

Here's an example:

```
function loginRouteHandler(req, res) {
  user.findOne(
    {
      where: {
        userName: req.body.userName,
      },
    },
  )
    .then((data) => {
      if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, data.password)) {
        req.session.userName = req.body.userName;
        req.session.password = req.body.password;
        console.log(req.session);
        res.status(200).send('Success!');
      } else {
        res.status(400).send('some text');
      }
    });
}
```

UPDATE: you're also not getting the output of the fetch response with `.text()` or `.json()`. You have to update the fetch call to the following:

```
fetch(/* stuff */).then((response)=>{
if(response.ok){
  console.log(response)
}
else {
  console.log("a problem")
}
return response.text()
}).then((data)=>{
console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: thanks i modified the code , it gives me now undefined on the console

Comment: In the first .then put `return response.text()` at the end. Otherwise the first parameter will be undefined. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: You should also probably add a `.catch()` clause and throw an error instead of console.logging "a problem"

Comment: You are right , thanks youu i'm gonna rework my code

Answer (score 0):

Remove `ok` from response.ok

Remove .then((data)=>{ console.log(data) });

And check console log.

```
}).then((response)=>{
if(response){
  console.log(response)
}
else {
  console.log("a problem")
}
}).then((data)=>{
console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: thanks you so much , now it gives me undefined on the console